# How to create the affix and dic files for postgresql text search

Tags: postgresql, full-text-search, stop-words, affix

I wanna use postgresql's text search capability for one of my projects. The language supported gonna be in english and indonesian. Unfortunately, I can't find indonesian config to be used. (example is here https://www.cs.hmc.edu/~geoff/ispell-dictionaries.html)

Looking at https://www.postgresql.org/docs/11/textsearch-dictionaries.html, it seems I can make my own custom stopwords, affix, and dic files. I already found and load the stopwords file (from https://github.com/masdevid/ID-Stopwords), meanwhile for the affix (the rule looks like here http://indodic.com/affixeng.html) I can't seem to find the file, or the way to write the affix/dic file.

Can someone point out to me how, or possibly where can I find some information in more details?

Comment: What kind of dictionary do you want to create?

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe it doesn't need to be too complex, as long as stopwords (done already) and can do stemming (in which I need affix config)

Comment: If you want to create an Ispell dictionary, you have to learn Ispell and the grammar rules of the language.

Comment: it is my native language actually, and the link I had given above is the formal rules. What I currently need (want?) is the syntax/format to write the affix/dic file, or does postgres follow some other standards (that can be more easily searched)? Can't find the specific of the format in the docs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [Ispell link](https://www.cs.hmc.edu/~geoff/ispell.html) referenced in the PostgreSQL documentation has the following information:

> Complete documentation for ispell, including documentation of the affix-file format, comes with the distribution kit in Unix manual-page format. If you have ispell installed on your machine, you should be able to type "`man ispell`" to view it. For convenience and browsing, the [primary manual page for ispell](https://www.cs.hmc.edu/~geoff/ispell-man.html) is also available online.

You will have to study that, then you can create an affix file.